# Get a cursor for an entire collection with mongo c driver

Tags: c, mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I am using mongo c driver 1.1 with mongo version 3.0. I need to write a function that gets a cursor to a collection. I found the following example in the documentation.

http://api.mongodb.org/c/1.1.0/mongoc_cursor_t.html

```
   collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "test", collection_name);
   cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection,
                                    MONGOC_QUERY_NONE,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    &query,
                                    NULL,  /* Fields, NULL for all. */
                                    NULL); /* Read Prefs, NULL for default */
```

I want to do exactly this, except i want to have no query (Match all documents in the collection)

Comment: Did you saw my answer? Did it worked for you or I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an *empty query specifier* to find all documents in the database "mydb" and collection "mycoll" as in the following snippet:

```
collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "mydb", "mycoll");
query = bson_new ();
cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);
```

Full documentation [here](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/finding-document.html).